# Entity Framework Entity Builder not overwriting default value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

EDIT May, 18th 2020: This is not solved, but I worked around it.

I use Entity Framework Fluent Api to create domain classes. One of the properties has the mapping `HasDefaultValue(true)`.

When I try to insert data into the database, and setting this property to `false`, something overrides this and still inserts `true` in the database.

Entity Builder

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Shifts> builder)
{
   builder.ToTable("Shifts");

   builder.HasKey(s => s.ID);

   builder.Property(s => s.Available)
     .HasDefaultValue(true);   
}
```

Controller

```
Shifts newShift = new Shifts()
{
   Name = shiftOne,
   Available = false,
   // other fields               
};
```

Now when I save it like this:

```
_unitOfWork.Shifts.Add(newShift);
await _unitOfWork.Commit();
```

The debugger shows that my newShift object has a field `Available` set to `false`, when hitting the `unitOfWork.Shifts.Add(newShift);` line.

After the commit, that changes to `true` all of the sudden, and when I look in the database, I see the field is set to `true`. Code runs without errors.

How can I prevent this and have the correct value entered?

EDIT with solution: I have removed `.HasDefaultValue`. Now it works, obviously, but I still don't know what caused the behavior in the first place.

Comment: Which EF version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 ways of fixing your issue:

1. Make your "Available" property do nullable bool - it should do
   or
2. Remove that

   .HasDefaultValue(true)

and add a constructor to your Shifts

```
public Shifts(){
   Available=true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I decided to get rid of the `.HasDefaultValue`.